# Hiding UWP application from taskbar

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm trying to hide UWP application from taskbar.

I found two way from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20458517/1827594) for windows application but that's not works in UWP.

1.Delete `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` and add `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` to windows styles.

2.Delete it from taskbar with `ITaskbarList::DeleteTab`.

I Have problem with handler. The `MainWindowHandle` is empty! I know its because of the UWP, But how can I do it now?

```
Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName("Microsoft.StickyNotes");
IntPtr windowHandle = p[0].Handle;
var taskbarList = (ITaskbarList)new CoTaskbarList();
taskbarList.HrInit();
taskbarList.DeleteTab(windowHandle); //doesn't do anything
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, You can't hide it. Running in foreground app cannot be hidden from task bar. UWP doesn't support it at all yet.
But you can use background tasks. [Here's an answer for a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46828926/8171157).