# UWP How to hide the app?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

In my application their is one option to hide the app. Whenever user clicks on hide the app window as well as the app icon from task bar should be get hidden.
How to achieve this in UWP?

Comment: And then how will it come back?

Comment: By pressing the hot key(shortcut key) used for the same(to hide/ unhide app). And when it is visible, the app will be in the previous state as before app was hidden.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such API in UWP, wouldn't it work for you like freezing your app like Lock option in windows?

Comment: No I just want to hide the app from screen

Comment: I believe that there are no option to minimize or hide the uwp app by itself.  similar question -->   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43883976/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is not supported (yet) on UWP. 
If you look at the UWP Skype, it always remain visible from the taskbar along with all the other apps. A UWP app cannot register by itself a global shortcut to be launched.

Minimized UWP applications are suspended by the OS when it wants/needs and will not be able to perform any job. If you hide your application you will be suspended and will not be able to perform any work. The only exception being if you request an extended execution time, your application will be allowed to run while minimized. They will still be limits but they are more battery/lock screen bounds.

If you really want to hide your app, you should just close your app window and rely on some background tasks to perform the work you might want to do when hidden/stopped.

This should be a good reading:

[Windows 10 universal Windows platform (UWP) app lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle)

[Support your app with background tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks)

[Postpone app suspension with extended execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-minimized-with-extended-execution)

Comment: When minimized, the app can actually continue to do work, using the ExtendedExecutionSession API. You might want to update your answer. Other than that the answer is correct.